# How can I correct my where case statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I have the following query that fails to run stating "History queries must contain at least one valid tagname".  This one has me stumped.

```
    DECLARE @tag varchar(255),
        @sqlstring varchar(4000)
SET @tag = 'rm01'

SELECT
  value
FROM StringHistory e
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  badge,
  lastname AS name
FROM [LOCALSERVER].[my_log].[dbo].[local_Operators]
WHERE type = '''op''') u
  ON e.value = u.badge
  AND e.TagName = 'first' + (CASE
    WHEN @tag = 'rm01' THEN '03'
  END) + '_dat_badge'
  AND DateTime >= DATEADD(HH, -12, GETDATE())
  AND DateTime <= GETDATE()
```

I am assuming it has to do with the case statement and a single quote?  because if I remove the case statement and just use ('03') the query runs.

Thank You

Comment: the case has no else specified

Comment: @Ako `ELSE` is optional in `CASE`, but it returns `NULL` if there's no match. You might want to add `ELSE ''` to the `CASE`

Comment: Sounds like a custom error in your code somewhere.   Is this query part of a stored procedure or batch?

Comment: Sorry I did have the else in prior but was no aid in running Qry.

Comment: No store procedure or batch.

Comment: @Alsjka what did you specify in the `ELSE`?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the query that DOES work (where you replace the CASE statement with '03').

Comment: If this isn't part of a larger batch of code, then why do you have a sqlstring variable that isn't used in the query?    There is nothing wrong with your CASE statement.   The error occurs because of something you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CASE`-expression has no `ELSE` specified. This will result in a `NULL` being returned, which will lead to `'first' + NULL + '_dat_badge'` which in turn is `NULL`.
I believe adding the `ELSE` with an empty string will solve the error.

```
SELECT
  value
FROM StringHistory e
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  badge,
  lastname AS name
FROM [LOCALSERVER].[my_log].[dbo].[local_Operators]
WHERE type = '''op''') u
  ON e.value = u.badge
  AND e.TagName = 'first' + (CASE
    WHEN @tag = 'rm01' THEN '03' ELSE ''
  END) + '_dat_badge'
  AND DateTime >= DATEADD(HH, -12, GETDATE())
  AND DateTime <= GETDATE()
```